# How to edit data from a feature in Heron

Tags: editing, heron-mapping-client

I'm new to Heron and I would like to know how to add a feature to a layer and to create a custom form to edit data from a feature.

I've tried a few examples, I can select a feature but can't change the data.

Answer (score 1):

Heron is based on GeoExt. This GeoExt sample should get you started on what you're looking to do (assuming it isn't an example you've already tried.)

[GeoExt - FeatureEditing working example](http://dev.geoext.org/geoext/ux/geoext.ux/ux/FeatureEditing/examples/feature-editor-grid.html)

[GeoExt - FeatureEditing documentation and installation info](http://trac.geoext.org/wiki/ux/FeatureEditing)